# How do I limit the amount of parallel events per resource?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

When using the Fullcalender-Libary you can, by default, have several events happening at the same time for a single resource.

Hence, it can sometimes be needed to only have one event at a time (e.g. One person can only be at one event at a time…) So can one restrict the overlapping/paralleling of events on input? Meaning that only one event can be entered for one resource at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) setting in fullCalendar to restrict whether events can overlap when the user is trying to select an area of the calendar for a new event.

This option can be set either `true` or `false`, or for more control you can provide a custom callback which must return a boolean to indicate whether the overlap the user is attempting is allowed or not.

- If the option is `true` (the default), the user can select any period of time.
- If it's `false`, the user cannot select any time period which overlaps with (part of) an existing event on the calendar
- If you provide a custom callback function, the code in the callback makes the decision

The documentation gives a simple example of using the callback as follows:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [ /* event data here */ ]
  selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return event.rendering === 'background';
  }
});
```

This will allow an overlap if the overlapping event is marked as a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events), but not for other events.

Answer (score -1):

Use Async/Await or Promises so that one call or one method must wait for another to be finished.

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood the question and the context of it. We're talking about displaying items on a calendar...nothing to do with Promises.